# verifying username/password from text file in java

Tags: java, authentication, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to create a very basic login system that verifies the username and password that the user enters to the ones stored in a text file. I have looked at other examples on this website and other places but I have been unable to get them to work properly. I know that text files are not secure, but this is just for learning purposes and will not be implemented in anything serious.

The text file it is reading contains these two lines in the format "username,password"

> student1,student1
>
> student2,student2

The goal is for the If statement to verify the login credentials and then open the next frame. I haven't added the code for that part yet because I have been unable to debug everything up to that.

Here is the code:

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           File loginf = new File("users.txt");

                try{
                    Scanner read = new Scanner(loginf);
                    read.useDelimiter(",");
                    boolean login = false;
                    while(read.nextLine() !=null){
                           String user = read.next();
                           String pass = read.next();
                           read.next();
                           if(username.getText().equals(user) && passwordField.getText().equals(pass)){
                              login = true;
                              break;                 
                           }
                        }
                        if(login)
                           System.out.println("good"); //using for testing purposes
                        else {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
                           username.setText("");
                           passwordField.setText("");
                        }
                    read.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException qwerty){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find a text file");
                }
           }
        });
```

Thanks for all of your help in advance.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're running into?

Comment: `||` means `or`. You want `&&`, which means `and`.

Comment: I keep encountering this exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException @Scraniel

Comment: Edit the question and write what you encounter

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like this.

```
    Scanner read = new Scanner(loginf);
    read.useDelimiter("\\n|,");
    boolean login = false;
    while(read.hasNext()){
       String user = read.next();
       String pass = read.next();
       System.out.println(user + " " + pass);
    }
```

I did

- delete your third call to read.next(), what did cause your Exception
- replace readLine() because this would make you skip some lines
- add the new line character as a delimiter since your data is also split by this

Answer (score 0):

Change the delimiter to `:`, throw away the `Scanner`, and use `java.util.Properties.`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove read.next() line after taking user and pass. It will work for sure.